# How to carry POST variables to another file?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am working on a form, and want to save a copy of every form submitted. The problem is the form's action is a counting file, that makes each file saved count up once. For example, the third form submitted is named "3.php", and the tenth form submitted is named "10.php". When I try to write the POST variable top the new file, it is gone. Anyway I could write their responses to a new document with my counting files code?

Form code on main file:

```
<form action="count.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="formItem1">
    <input type="text" name="formItem2" required>
    <input type="text" name="formItem4" required>
    <input type="text" name="formItem5" required>
    <input type="text" name="formItem6" required>
    <input type="submit" name="Click" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Count.php code:

```
<body>
<?php
define('countlog.txt', __DIR__ . "./");

if (file_exists('countlog.txt')) {
    # If File exists - read its content
    $start = (int) file_get_contents('countlog.txt');
} else {
    # If No File Found - Create new File
    $start =  1;
    @file_put_contents('countlog.txt', "$start");
}

# When Form Submitted
if (isset($_POST) and isset($_POST['Click']) and $_POST['Click'] == "Submit") {
    $file_name = "{$start}.php";
    $template = file_get_contents('template.php');
    @file_put_contents("./submissions/" . $file_name, "$template");
    # Update Counter too
    $start = $start + 1;
    @file_put_contents('countlog.txt', "$start", 1);
    echo "Generated Filename - $file_name";
}
?>
</body>
```

Template.php code:

```
echo "<h1>Answer1: " . $formItem1 . "</h1>";
echo "<h1>Answer2: " . $formItem2 . "</h1>";
echo "<h1>Answer3: " . $formItem3 . "</h1>";
echo "<h1>Answer4: " . $formItem4 . "</h1>";
echo "<h1>Answer5: " . $formItem5 . "</h1>";
echo "<h1>Answer: " . $formItem6 . "</h1>";
```

Comment: I can't see where you are referencing `$_POST['formItem1']`? Do you use `extract($_POST)` somewhere? BTW, this seems like a very complicated way of achieving something quite straightforward? If your goal is to store the submitted data to file, couldn't you just json encode the posted data and save it on a new line in a single text file rather than messing around with different files and a countlog?

Comment: @Tristan Well I wanted to have the files count up, which is fine. But the post values are saved when the form is submitted, and when I try to write them to the newly generated file, they aren't there. I have also tried making the post values a regular variable, but get an error when trying to store them. Maybe a way to store the post values and call them in the new file will help?

Comment: @Tristan Also, the reason I have the count log is to save each form submission, and the count log gives each submission a unique file name.

Comment: This line `$template = file_get_contents('template.php');` makes the content of `template.php` a string. If you want to evaluate it to replace the variables with the posted values you need to use `eval()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sessions. Create a session on each page with `session_start();` Store the post value using the session global array. eg. `$_SESSION['yourValue'] = POST['yourValue'];`. Now on the rest of the pages you should be able to access the value. e.g

```
$yourValue = $_SESSION['yourValue'];
```

Comment: Which file would I add this to?

Comment: Add $yourValue = SESSION['yourValue']; to the new file.

Comment: "Notice: Use of undefined constant SESSION - assumed 'SESSION'" on the line I put your code. Don't I have to define this value somewhere?

Comment: Did you start the session using session_start(); I edited my my answer. I made some syntax errors originally.

Comment: THANK YOU! I like my answers to be short too!

Answer (score 1):

IF you use `$template = file_get_contents('template.php');` it will make the content of `template.php` a string, and the variables will not be evaluated.

You could use `eval()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php to evaluate a string as PHP code. I would not recommend this method, but if you want to use it you will need to `return`, rather than `echo` the template otherwise the template will be echoed to the browser rather than the string you want to save to file.

template.php

```
return "<h1>Answer1: " . $formItem1 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer2: " . $formItem2 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer3: " . $formItem3 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer4: " . $formItem4 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer5: " . $formItem5 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer: " . $formItem6 . "</h1>";
```

count.php

```
$template = file_get_contents('template.php');
$template = eval($template);
```

It would be much easier/better to `include` the template, and the code will execute, thus populating the `$template` variable.

template.php

```
<?php
$template = "<h1>Answer1: " . $formItem1 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer2: " . $formItem2 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer3: " . $formItem3 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer4: " . $formItem4 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer5: " . $formItem5 . "</h1>".
"<h1>Answer: " . $formItem6 . "</h1>";
?>
```

count.php

```
include('template.php');
```

Both methods assume you have used `extract($_POST);` to import variables from an array into the current symbol table.

Comment: Thanks, but I got the other one to work before I saw your post. With his method, I also got to make the written data minified